# find form -> check all boxes if value equals what i say

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I am trying to do a simple function to find the surrounding form, thereafter find all the checkboxes with a specified value and then just check em all :)

html

```
<form action='bla bla bla'>
  <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='checkAll(2);'>Check all 2s</a>

  <input type='checkbox' value='1' /> 1
  <input type='checkbox' value='1' /> 1
  <input type='checkbox' value='2' /> 2
  <input type='checkbox' value='2' /> 2
  <input type='checkbox' value='3' /> 3
  <input type='checkbox' value='4' /> 3
</form>
```

js

```
function checkAll(i) {
  var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find('input[type=checkbox][value='+i+']');
  checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

But absolutely nothing happens. What goes wrong? :)

Comment: how you call this `checkAll(i)` function? where did you get the `this` within this function?

Comment: @theCodeParadox The `checkAll` function is triggered by clicking on an anchor that's part of the form, so the `this` will refer to the anchor that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `this` inside `checkAll` without a correct initialization. When `checkAll()` is executed, `this` will be bound to to global object (`window`, in this case).

The clicked `<a>` element is available through `this` only to the Javascript code inside the `onclick` attribute. You have to pass `this` to `checkAll()` as a parameter.

The HTML code has to be changed like this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='checkAll(this, 2);'>Check all 2s</a>
```

The Javascript code will be:

```
function checkAll(el, i) {
  var checkboxes = $(el).closest('form').find('input[type=checkbox][value=' + i + ']');
  checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I couldn't see anything necessarily wrong with your code, trying to create a jsFiddle with it resulted in a Javascript error about the checkAll function not being defined when clicking on the anchor - I think this may be an unrelated scope issue due to the way jsFiddle executes Javascript onLoad, but I'm not 100% sure.

I opted instead to do away with the `onclick` attribute of the link, store the value to compare against in a custom data attribute (`data-value`), then bind the click event handler (based on a class added to the link) using jQuery.

New HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="bla bla bla">
  <a href="#" class="checkall" data-value="2">Check all 2s</a>

  <input type='checkbox' value='1' /> 1
  <input type='checkbox' value='1' /> 1
  <input type='checkbox' value='2' /> 2
  <input type='checkbox' value='2' /> 2
  <input type='checkbox' value='3' /> 3
  <input type='checkbox' value='4' /> 3
</form>
```

And then the jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.checkall').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var checkboxes = $this.closest('form').find('input:checkbox[value="'+$this.data('value')+'"]');
        checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

Comment: The answer from @frm was the cleanest and best in my opinion.. great answer tho :)

Comment: My answer was a fix for your particular problem. This answer, on the other side, is a better example of [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and you should consider this as a better approach from a general point of view.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
function checkAll(i, ref) {
    $(ref).siblings('input[type=checkbox][value="' + i + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
$('form :checkbox').click(function() {
    checkAll($(this).prop('value'), this)
});
```